# Print custom barcode label using TCPDF

Tags: tcpdf, barcode-printing

I have a project to print barcode in roll label like 
[this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwQ6d.png)
 It is possible to do these things with tcpdf? At first the barcode should be placed at bottom and rotated 180° but i think its impossible to rotate the barcode using start transform and rotate since its only for graphic. So i tried to rotate the text, its works but only in another page to test that with dummy data. How to implement it in this code since im using serializeTCPDFtagParameters?

```
foreach($product as $row){
$description = $row['description'];
$barcode = $row['barcode_code'];
$barcode = $pdf->serializeTCPDFtagParameters(array($barcode, 'C128','','',25,10,0.5, array('position'=>'S','border'=>false,'padding'=>0, 'fgcolor'=>array(0,0,0), 'bgcolor'=>array(255,255,255), 'text'=>true, 'font'=>'helvetica','fontsize'=>7, 'stretchtext'=>6), 'N'));

$html .= '
<table width="60mm" height="15mm" cellpadding="3" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td><tcpdf method="write1DBarcode" params="'.$barcode.'" /></td>
    </tr>';

    '<tr>
        <td> '.$description.'</td>
    </tr>';
$html = '</table>';
$item = $item+1;}
$pdf->setFont('helvetica', '','4');
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true,0,true,0);
$pdf->lastPage();
$pdf->output('test.pdf','I');
```

And should i using cell to make the label side by side per table row? Im gonna use it for labeling jewelry and accessories. Is there any other alternative?

ps. Sorry for my poor english.